# How to get last document of each users group by userName in MongoDB with Java driver?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, mongo-collection

I have created a collection for track the user sessions. I want to get the last session of each user according to log in time. Suppose there are some documents in my collection.

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"LkNkGFrvldtTyHmLp5CirA=="),
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:37:17.620Z"),
    "userName" : "testUser1",
    "loggedOnDuration" : NumberLong(10),
    "loginTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:37:17.620Z"),
    "logoutTime" : ISODate("2017-09-23T06:37:17.620Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"B0R7SkeZ30rCjsp/Kftphw=="),
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:42:17.620Z"),
    "userName" : "testUser1",
    "loggedOnDuration" : NumberLong(10),
    "loginTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:42:17.620Z"),
    "logoutTime" : ISODate("2017-09-23T06:37:17.620Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"B0R7SkeZ30rCjsp/Kftphw=="),
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:45:17.620Z"),
    "userName" : "testUser2",
    "loggedOnDuration" : NumberLong(10),
    "loginTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:45:17.620Z"),
    "logoutTime" : ISODate("2017-09-23T06:37:17.620Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"B0R7SkeZ30rCjsp/Kftphw=="),
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:50:17.620Z"),
    "userName" : "testUser2",
    "loggedOnDuration" : NumberLong(10),
    "loginTime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:50:17.620Z"),
    "logoutTime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:59:17.620Z"),
}
```

I just want to get one document for each user with the maximum createdTime. The output should be like this-

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"B0R7SkeZ30rCjsp/Kftphw=="),
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:42:17.620Z"),
    "userName" : "testUser1",
    "loggedOnDuration" : NumberLong(10),
    "loginTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:42:17.620Z"),
    "logoutTime" : ISODate("2017-09-23T06:37:17.620Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"B0R7SkeZ30rCjsp/Kftphw=="),
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:50:17.620Z"),
    "userName" : "testUser2",
    "loggedOnDuration" : NumberLong(10),
    "loginTime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:50:17.620Z"),
    "logoutTime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:59:17.620Z"),
}
```

I am using MongoCollection class for MongoDB operations. How can I get this output by using MongoCollection library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation framework, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/,  to group the session documents by userName and get the max loginTime. Using the mongo shell the aggegation pipeline would look like this:

```
db.session.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id:"$userName", loginTime: {$max: "$loginTime"}}}
])
```

a single stage that groups on userName.

This can be recreated in java using `BasicDBObjects`:

```
final MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = database.getCollection("sessions");

List<Bson> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
BasicDBObject groupStage = new BasicDBObject("$group",
  new BasicDBObject("_id", "$userName")
  .append("loginTime", new BasicDBObject("$max", "$loginTime")));
pipeline.add(groupStage);

AggregateIterable<Document> result = mongoCollection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think this should work:

```
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("your_collection");

    collection.find(Filters.eq("userName", "aUserName"))
            .sort(Sorts.descending("loginTime"))
            .first(); //get highest element
```

Or if you want mulitple entries, just use `.limit(<amount>)` and iterate through the results.

Comment: It will be work only for a single user but I want to get a max entry of every user(distinct user).

Comment: Then just use find without any arguments. -> `collection.find().sort....`, so you can get all collections entries.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `$sort` and `$first` operators for achieving this.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate( [
    { $sort : { userName : -1, createdTime: -1 } },
    {
        $group: 
        {
            _id: {userName:"$userName" }, 
            maxCreatedItem: 
            { 
                $first:  
                { 
                    _id:"$_id", 
                    createdTime: "$createdTime", 
                    userName: "$userName", 
                    loggedOnDuration: "$loggedOnDuration", 
                    loginTime:"$loginTime", 
                    logoutTime:"$logoutTime" 
                } 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$maxCreatedItem" }
    }
 ])
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e99f9bb0e16378d5e80d48"),
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:42:17.620Z"),
    "userName" : "testUser1",
    "loggedOnDuration" : NumberLong(10),
    "loginTime" : ISODate("2017-09-22T06:42:17.620Z"),
    "logoutTime" : ISODate("2017-09-23T06:37:17.620Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e99f9bb0e16378d5e80d4a"),
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:50:17.620Z"),
    "userName" : "testUser2",
    "loggedOnDuration" : NumberLong(10),
    "loginTime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:50:17.620Z"),
    "logoutTime" : ISODate("2017-09-24T06:59:17.620Z")
}
```